# Sorting two stacks by using structs

Tags: sorting, struct, stack

There are 3 stacks - A, B, C

Stacks A and B are sorted (the number on the top of the stack is the biggest). Stack C is Empty Only 5 operation are allowed:

push,
pop,
top, 
is_empty,
create

We need to write a function that receives the stacks A and B, moves all the numbers in stacks A and B to stack C and stack C must be sorted (biggest Number is on top).

I have the algorithm :

> Compare top of A with top of B

```
Pop the least element and push to stack C

Repeat step 2 until any of the stack ( A or B) becomes empty

Move remaining elements from non-empty stack to C. Now you have all the elements in C  but in ascending order. (That is least element at top).

Move all the elements from C to A. (Contents in A are in descending order)

Move all the elements from A to B. (Contents in B are in ascending order)

Move all the elements from B to C.
```

and i started to write the code but there are errors and i don't know why !

the code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX_MEMBERS 10
typedef struct
{
    int num;
}ITEM;

typedef struct
{
    ITEM a[MAX_MEMBERS];
    int top;
}STACK;

void create_stack(STACK *s)
{
    s->top=-1;
}

int is_empty(STACK *s)
{
    return s->top==-1;
}

int is_full(STACK *s)
{
    return s->top==MAX_MEMBERS-1;
}

ITEM pop(STACK *s)
{
    return s->a[s->top--];
}

void (STACK *s,ITEM *item)
{
    s->a[++s->top]=*item;
}

ITEM top(STACK *s)
{
    return s->a[s->top];
}

void sort (STACK *a,STACK *b,STACK *c)
{
    while(!is_empty(&a)||!is_empty(&b))
        if(top(&a)>top(&b))
            push(&c,pop(&b));

    if(!is_empty(&a))
    {
        while(!is_empty(&a))
            push(&c,pop(&a));
    }

    else
    {
        while(!is_empty(&b))
            push(&c,pop(&b));
    }

    while(!is_empty(&c))
        push(&a,pop(&c));

    while(!is_empty(&a))
        push(&b,pop(&a));

    while(!is_empty(&b))
        push(&c,pop(&b));

}

void main(void)
{
    STACK a,b,c;
    create_stack(&a);
    create_stack(&b);
    create_stack(&c);
    sort(&a,&b,&c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pop the highest element and push it to C.

To push all elements onto C in reversed order you need the highest element at the bottom of C (this value must be pushed first). If a > b Then: pop a, push c.

Anyway, your code doesn't seem to be very safe. Have a look at the following:

```
while(!is_empty(&a)||!is_empty(&b))
    if(top(&a)>top(&b))
```

let's assume that a is empty and b is not so that a.top equals to -1 and b.top is in range 0 to MAX_MEMBERS - 1. Since one of the stacks is not empty the condition is true.
By calling top(&a) following code is executed:

return a[-1]; //Error: Index out of bounds

```
This is how your code is resolved.
is_empty(&a) returns true
!is_empty(&a) returns false
(false || true) returns true

while(false || true)
    if( top(&a) > top(&b) )
```

Anyway, i doubt that your code does even compile.

```
void (STACK *s,ITEM *item)
{
    s->a[++s->top]=*item;
}
```

This should be that:

```
void push(STACK *s,ITEM *item)
{
    s->a[++s->top]=*item;
}
```

Also consider that:

```
void main(void)
{
    STACK a,b,c;
    create_stack(&a); //stack a is created, contains no elements
    create_stack(&b); //stack b is created, contains no elements
    create_stack(&c); //stack c is created, contains no elements
    sort(&a,&b,&c); //sort which elements of the stack?
}
```

Comment: But where do you see that i called "top(&a)" if we assume that "A" is empty ?

Comment: sorry can you edit the code cause i dont get it .. can u insert the code and compile the code without having any errors ?

Comment: noo , its just the beggining of the code .. i didnt finish it yet .. i need u to see if its right or not .. to continue or not

Comment: how i can insert values to stacks a and b ?

Comment: Have a look at it yourself. Try to compile it and try to understand the output of the compiler. The operator `>` of course does not work for your struct, it only  works on primitives. Try `typedef int ITEM;` if you want it to be called item.